# MySQL query, between 2 tables to get the right answer

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this script, I didn't make it, that get stats from our gameservers, then put them into a database, which works fine.

I also have another script, I didn't make it, that get the data from the database and displays the stats on a webpage, this is where my problem is.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
    $dogtags=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT SUM(`Count`) FROM ".$sqlprefix."dogtags".$suffix.""));
```

Then call it by

```
define("DOGTAGS", $dogtags['0']);
```

The problem with this, all 3 servers show the same dogtags, and not for each server.

So the MySQL query needs to be changed, I believe and I need help with that.

Ok I have 2 tables, and I need data from both in the query, to get the right answer

```
tbl_dogtags
KillerID
VictimID
Count

tbl_server_player
StatsID
ServerID
PlayerID
```

I need to take `KillerID` from `tbl_dogtags` and matach it with `PlayerID` from `tbl_server_player`, then do a where `ServerID` from `tbl_server_player` to give me the answer and I am not sure how to do this.

So something like this

SUM(Count), KillerID = PlayerID  where ServerID

Can anyone help please?

Comment: The line `define("DOGTAGS", $dogtags['0']);` is not a call (not to mention that I doubt the syntax is really correct). There you assign the value of `$dogtags['0']` to the constant `DOGTAGS` so if you'd like to see the value you'd need to do `echo DOGTAGS;` which I think is **not** what you're looking for.

Comment: PHP, MySQL not really my thing, and it was how it was done for some reason. I presume it calls it that way and then display it on page, I really don't know. I have updated my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_dogtags d
INNER JOIN tbl_server_player sp ON d.KillerID = sp.PlayerId
WHERE sp.ServerID [THE_REST_OF_YOUR_CONDITION]
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, maybe the way I call it. I have updated the first post, please see there

Comment: What do you want to get exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

This query will do your work.

```
SELECT killerID FROM tbl_dogtags D, tbl_server_player P 
  ON D.KillerID=P.PlayerID 
  WHERE P.ServerId={your condition}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, maybe the way I call it. I have updated the first post, please see there

Answer (score 0):

Going to make thigns easy on myself and everyone else.

Just going to remove that stats.

Thanks for the asnwers